# Drupal with Near Realtime Search Solr

Tags: drupal, solr, indexing

I have to implement Near Realtime search for Solr, strictly connected with Drupal. After add/edit each node, trigger should run Solr to index new content ( via soft commit) , without rebuilding whole index. Hard commit. Hard commit/reindex will be run from cron and that part is easy. But how to make index of each new/edited node in NRS ?

I'm using: 
CentOS 6.4 (httpd + mysqld),
Solr 4.3.1 
Drupal 7 with apachesolr module,

I'll be grateful for any suggestions.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution that immediately indexes nodes on insert/update and only requires putting a little snippet of code into a custom module: https://www.drupal.org/node/1816462#comment-9093573

(Scroll up a bit to see implementation of *hook_entity_insert/update()*.)

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented NRS on various applications using the DIH by requesting delta-import command. Basically how it works is it keeps a timestamp record of when the last import was performed, and in your delta query you filter based on that timestamp. I have a job that tickles the delta command once every 5 minutes, but you could set the interval for what ever your requirement is.

Examples here.

[DataImportHandler Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler)

Look for Delta-Import command.